# Can't install Dota on steam

Tags: 14.04, games, steam

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm unable to install DOTA2 on steam. I have a game backup which I'm unable to load because I get this screen.[image: Check the size available option] Please help!!

Comment: Check 'Disk space available' . It shows zero MB and I'm not able to successfully 'change location for install'...

Comment: I see from the screen shot that you ran it from a terminal, did you use `sudo` You don't want to use `sudo` for steam, this may explain the issue, also how much space is in your /home ? and is it encrypted ?

Comment: system monitor shows 239 GB available in /home.

Comment: How do I check if my /home directory is encrypted?

Comment: You would of had to set it up when you installed, it just means you need a password to access it, I think, you would know if you had it.

Comment: I just noticed you are trying to install a back up ? Was this made on the linux version of steam ? That could be an issue, What does it say if you just try getting it from steam store ? Check this for to find out if it is just installing back up issue or installing anything issue.

Comment: well then it's not encrypted...!! But I can't change install directory which is also a problem...!! How can I fix that?

Comment: I get an error message saying 'New Steam ibrary folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permission' .

Comment: Based on a forum I was reading on this error, browse too /home/.steam/steam and find `steamapps`, if this folder is called `SteamApps` not `steamapps` then in terminal `cd ~/.steam/steam` then `ln -s SteamApps steamapps` is the best solution from here https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/666827316152433246/

Comment: Folder name is 'steamapps', not 'SteamApps'.

Comment: How do I make steam download to '/home' by default. I think steam is trying to install the game on my '/' directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26341/discussion-between-mark-kirby-and-sy13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1479093

(only update your O.S. for solve the problem)

Answer (score 2):

The latest kernel update (kernel ending in '59') on 14.04, and which I installed today, has somehow blocked use of certain parts of my computer's file system.  I'm no expert, but the last readable message during boot ended with 'file system blocked'.  No idea why, but previous kernels seem to be working OK, and allow Steam to install/access games with no problems.  After the first boot from the new kernel ('59') which I will be leaving alone for now, I was informed from the GUI of some kind of system error which I sent to the developers.  Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah I had the same issue. I'm facing problems with permissions.

Comment: My system is running an 3.13.0-59 kernel.

Comment: You were right. It is the latest kernel update that is causing the problems. I loaded the older kernel version and it worked without a hitch. Thanks.